# camera preview with camera2 library

Tags: android

Is there any way to have a camera preview using the camera2 library while running the application? I only need one method which is able to show in the app the camera preview (not taking pictures or opening the camera APP).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CameraView](https://github.com/google/cameraview), an unofficial support library widget for drawing camera preview easily (It can also take snapshots, but you can ignore that part).